# Django Rest Framework: nested serializer for duplicate rows, in the case of foreign key

Tags: django-rest-framework, foreign-keys, many-to-many, drf-nested-routers, drf-queryset

serializer.py

```
class Car(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    geography=Geography(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['car_id', 'geography']
```

models.py

```
 class Car(models.Model):
      car_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
      geography = models.ForeignKey('Geography' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

the object that I want :

```
 [
{
    "car_id": 1,
    "geography":[ {
        "key": 1,
        "name": "India"},

    {"key": 1,
          "name": "China"
}
   ]        
 } 
]
```

the object that I am getting:

```
[
{
    "car_id": 1,
    "geography": {
        "key": 1,
        "name": "India"}

}
]
```

The data that I am working with has duplicate values for car_id and key attributes. I have another confusion whether it should be foreign key or many to many field. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You declare `geography` as a ForeignKey in `Car`.
In natural language, this translates to *One car **belongs** to Geography*,
while in your problem description, it's more like *One car **has many** to Geography*, which related so M2M relation ship.

So... in your models it should become:

```py
class Car(models.Model):
      car_id = models.IntegerField(null=False)
      geographies = models.ManyToManyField('Geography' ,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
      # take care: I changed field's name
```

and in your serializer:

```py
class Car(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    geographies=Geography(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ['car_id', 'geographies']
```

Comment: I tried with many to many relations but now I am getting errors while importing data into postgresql, also it has created another table for many to many field itself